# Inject service in another service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have UserService and MissionService.

Is it ok to inject MissionService in UserSerivce or vice versa?

If yes, what about unit testing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Of course you can and it is perfectly fine. But I recommend that you use method-injection in order to allow you to set the instance at runtime without using using reflection (you can create an instance manually).

---

For example:

```
@Service
public class MissionService { }

@Service
public class UserService {
    private MissionService missionService;

    @Autowired
    public void setMissionService(MissionService missionService) {
        this.missionService = missionService;
    }
}
```

This allows you to create both services using regular Java without Spring:

```
MissionService missionService = new MissioNService();
UserService userService = new UserService();
userService.setMissionService(missionService);
```

---

**Caution: You have to take care of not building dependency cycles.** *It is not set that Spring resolves them, I think*

Comment: If it is a required dependency then it is better to use Constructor injection over method injection to make it explicit that you need to provide the dependent class. That way someone can't instantiate the class and start using other methods that rely on that dependent service.

Comment: @ShawnClark When you say that " someone can't instantiate the class and start using other methods that rely on that dependent service", think about it: if the method requires the service on its declaration, how would I be able to use it without giving the service class? Instead of requiring it on the constructor, I am requiring on the method. On both ways, I would not be able to use the method. But it won't be clear to me on which methods the injected dependency would be really needed if that was through the controller rather than the method.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. Both services is in the same package, both get instatiated in the right order, but 2nd sees null. Any ideas where to investigate?

Comment: For the investigation, check your component scan configuration. You must set the packages that contain the services to be scanned. If you don't specify a component scan configuration, all packages are scanned by default (I believe so).